# Как работают функции с объектами в Python?

Tags: python

**Код который я написал:**

```
def Test(int ,arr = []):   
  arr.append(int);
  print(arr);

Test(1);
Test(2);
Test(3);
```

**Ожидаю увидеть**

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

**В действительности получаю**

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Почему массив, который работает с разными функциями, имеет общую память? Как я могу заставить код делать то что мне нужно?

Comment: Потому что значения по умолчанию в функции создаются ровно один раз в момент объявления функции, соответственно и список тоже один. Хотите разные списки — создавайте новый список каждый раз заново внутри функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
#def Test(int ,arr = []):   
def test(int ,arr = None):  
    if not arr:
        arr = []
    arr.append(int);
    print(arr);

test(1);
test(2);
test(3);

test(5, ['Hello World',])
```

Comment: `x = []; test(6, x); assert x == [6]`